# Mesh won't move with Metarig

Tags: mesh, rigging

I got a used model of a remixed baby from Sketchfab remolded it figured out it was an STL made it an FBX, and after doing that I made the rig go into the shape of the model, after doing all that, when I went to pose mode the rig moves but not the mesh, I parented it too.